# ValueError: `tape` is required when a `Tensor` loss is passed. Received: loss=1950770.5, tape=None

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, causality

I am trying to implement the deconfounder of Wang and Blei ([https://colab.research.google.com/github/blei-lab/deconfounder_tutorial/blob/master/deconfounder_tutorial.ipynb](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)). The specified error has occurred in the line "train = optimizer.minimize(-elbo,var_list=[qb, qw, qw2, qz])". I am not sure if the var_list for my minimize()function is correct. I would be very grateful for help, since I unfortunately do not completely understand the code of Wang and Blei. I also tried to use tape=tf.GradientTape() but i didnt work.

```
def variational_model(qb_mean, qb_stddv, qw_mean, qw_stddv, 
                      qw2_mean, qw2_stddv, qz_mean, qz_stddv):
    qb = ed.Normal(loc=qb_mean, scale=qb_stddv, name="qb")
    qw = ed.Normal(loc=qw_mean, scale=qw_stddv, name="qw")
    qw2 = ed.Normal(loc=qw2_mean, scale=qw2_stddv, name="qw2")
    qz = ed.Normal(loc=qz_mean, scale=qz_stddv, name="qz")
    return qb, qw, qw2, qz


log_q = ed.make_log_joint_fn(variational_model)

def target(b, w, w2, z):
    """Unnormalized target density as a function of the parameters."""
    return log_joint(data_dim=data_dim,
                   latent_dim=latent_dim,
                   num_datapoints=num_datapoints,
                   stddv_datapoints=stddv_datapoints,
                   mask=1-holdout_mask,
                   w=w, z=z, w2=w2, b=b, x=x_train)

def target_q(qb, qw, qw2, qz):
    return log_q(qb_mean=qb_mean, qb_stddv=qb_stddv,
                 qw_mean=qw_mean, qw_stddv=qw_stddv,
                 qw2_mean=qw2_mean, qw2_stddv=qw2_stddv,
                 qz_mean=qz_mean, qz_stddv=qz_stddv,
                 qw=qw, qz=qz, qw2=qw2, qb=qb)

qb_mean = tf.Variable(np.ones([1, data_dim]), dtype=tf.float32)
qw_mean = tf.Variable(np.ones([latent_dim, data_dim]), dtype=tf.float32)
qw2_mean = tf.Variable(np.ones([latent_dim, data_dim]), dtype=tf.float32)
qz_mean = tf.Variable(np.ones([num_datapoints, latent_dim]), dtype=tf.float32)
qb_stddv = tf.nn.softplus(tf.Variable(0 * np.ones([1, data_dim]), dtype=tf.float32))
qw_stddv = tf.nn.softplus(tf.Variable(-4 * np.ones([latent_dim, data_dim]), dtype=tf.float32))
qw2_stddv = tf.nn.softplus(tf.Variable(-4 * np.ones([latent_dim, data_dim]), dtype=tf.float32))
qz_stddv = tf.nn.softplus(tf.Variable(-4 * np.ones([num_datapoints, latent_dim]), dtype=tf.float32))

qb, qw, qw2, qz = variational_model(qb_mean=qb_mean, qb_stddv=qb_stddv,
                                    qw_mean=qw_mean, qw_stddv=qw_stddv,
                                    qw2_mean=qw2_mean, qw2_stddv=qw2_stddv,
                                    qz_mean=qz_mean, qz_stddv=qz_stddv)


energy = target(qb, qw, qw2, qz)
entropy = -target_q(qb, qw, qw2, qz)

elbo = energy + entropy


optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.05)
train = optimizer.minimize(-elbo,var_list=[qb, qw, qw2, qz])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

t = []

num_epochs = 500

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(train)
        if i % 5 == 0:
            t.append(sess.run([elbo]))

        b_mean_inferred = sess.run(qb_mean)
        b_stddv_inferred = sess.run(qb_stddv)
        w_mean_inferred = sess.run(qw_mean)
        w_stddv_inferred = sess.run(qw_stddv)
        w2_mean_inferred = sess.run(qw2_mean)
        w2_stddv_inferred = sess.run(qw2_stddv)
        z_mean_inferred = sess.run(qz_mean)
        z_stddv_inferred = sess.run(qz_stddv)
        
print("Inferred axes:")
print(w_mean_inferred)
print("Standard Deviation:")
print(w_stddv_inferred)

plt.plot(range(1, num_epochs, 5), t)
plt.show()

def replace_latents(b, w, w2, z):

    def interceptor(rv_constructor, *rv_args, **rv_kwargs):
        """Replaces the priors with actual values to generate samples from."""
        name = rv_kwargs.pop("name")
        if name == "b":
            rv_kwargs["value"] = b
        elif name == "w":
            rv_kwargs["value"] = w
        elif name == "w":
            rv_kwargs["value"] = w2
        elif name == "z":
            rv_kwargs["value"] = z
        return rv_constructor(*rv_args, **rv_kwargs)

    return interceptor`
```

Comment: `optimizer.minimize(-elbo,var_list=[qb, qw, qw2, qz])`can't guess the gradient, since the loss is not a function which it can trace itself, so you have to manually record the gradient in the forward phase, and pass it to the optimizer

Comment: How can i manually record the gradient? Sorry to ask, but I have no experience in this area so far. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: that `tf.Session()` smells like TF1, so I'm not quite sure, but if you check https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch you can have some hints (particularly the part with `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:`)